# Roles lost from Multisite Wordpress Migration - User Role Editor

Tags: wordpress, editor, user-roles, multisite

I have lost all my Roles on my subsites created using user role editor for my wordpress multisite installation.

Has anyone come across this or know why this would happen.

I migrated the site via WP search and replace script the https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/ and everything else seems to work fine.

Any help would be much appreciated.